# How can I deal with different length of speech files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, speech

I do speech recognition using the TIDigits database which contains digits from zero to nine from different speakers (many files).

I need to extract the 39 MFCC features from each frame and combine them in one matrix (Features Matrix) for classification. I did the framing and windowing for each file and this produced unequal number of frames for each file.

The problem that I faced was the different number of frames because of the different length of speech files.

How can I deal with this issue without using the statistics formulas?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem recently when dealing with audio. What I did is basically by **trimming** the long MFCC features to match the shorter ones. It works well for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But by trimming the long MFCC features, did they affect on the accuracy of the classifier? or you didn't try?

Comment: @Sayf It will sure affect the accuracy of the classifier since it lose some features. However, the difference should be relatively small although I didn't compare them in very detail.

Comment: When you said you trimmed the long MFCC that's mean you discard features of some frames.. my shortest file contains 17 frames (25ms), and the longest one is 87 frames...So it's meaningless if I delete the 60 frames from the longest one, most of the signal will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem is that you want to store vectors of different lengths together, you have a few logical options:

1. Trim the vectors, your result will be a 39 by smallestVectorLength matrix
2. Padd the vectors, your result will be a 39 by largestVectorLength matrix
3. Use a cell array, your result will be the 39 vectors with their corresponding lenght

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
1st option will lost some info, 
2nd option I tries to pad zero but when I read about the Neural Network classifier and how it deals with the zero value in the vector, I excluded the 2nd option. 
3rd one It's work if I just want to store the vector. I have another stage for classification and that's why I think I need an equal MFCC vector Matrix.